CSS @Supports causes weird behaviour on iOS/Safari
I have an issue with some css implementation under iOS/Safari.
I'm currently working on a simple onepager website which has 3 content sections. Each section should fill the entire viewport.
For scrolling I have implemented a scroll-snap and (if supported) a parallax effect by applying "background-attachment: fixed;" to the background-image. As "fixed" is not supported by iOS/Safari, I have placed it in a "@supports" CSS rule.
However, this still breaks my layout under iOS/Safari. The background image seems to loose all the other rules/settings like width, height, etc.
When I remove the @supports rule everything works fine.
/*----------------------------------- Global/body styling -----------------------------------*/

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

#outer_wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.content_section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

#outer_wrapper .content_section:nth-child(1) {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.7) url("../media/hero_image-1_P576.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#outer_wrapper .content_section:nth-child(2) {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4) url("../media/hero_image-2_P576.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#outer_wrapper .content_section:nth-child(3) {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4) url("../media/hero_image-3_P576.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

@supports (background-attachment: fixed) {
    #outer_wrapper .content_section:nth-child(1) {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    #outer_wrapper .content_section:nth-child(2) {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    #outer_wrapper .content_section:nth-child(3) {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    


Are you certain that iOS Safari doesn’t think it supports background-attachment fixed, but its support is buggy. See https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment

Try to Apply background-attachment directly without @supports: Instead of using @supports, apply background-attachment: fixed directly to all sections and then override it for browsers that don't support it.
#outer_wrapper .content_section {
    background-attachment: fixed; /* Apply to all */
}

@supports not (background-attachment: fixed) {
    #outer_wrapper .content_section {
        background-attachment: scroll; /* Override for unsupported browsers */
    }
}


Did you try this? Because the problem seems to be that Safari IOS thinks it does support background-attachment: fixed - but it's buggy.

I haven't tried this, Can you share jsfiddle url and Safari Version

Try this e.g. in a snippet 

Its working fine on my safari, Showing cyan color as per given code, and when i remove not from @supports It shows pink color as expected

You have misinterpreted the results. Safari showing cyan means it is not picking up the @supports not… I.E. it thinks it does support background-attachment. It does partially support it but it is buggy as I said.

Oh, I got your point. I have checked Following Link and It shows that, They give full support after 15.4 version. I think you have older safari version and yes, you are right user might have older browsers on their devices. You can also check this link

Did you check further by clicking the … in the MDN table?  It says there is a bug although versions claim to implement fixed. I have IOS 16… and 17,,, versions.

I have reviewed MDN table with all versions, and There is no solution for it as of Now, We can only do one thing now, We have to manage it with position:fixed / absolute and Image tag

I would do it with a before pseudo element.

Yes, That's up to you. Thanks for the question and all your time for being active here. I have also increased my knowledge from your question by doing some research.
